# Debugging linux kernel with gdb via QEMU issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gdb

I am newbie in Linux kernel and I'm trying to debug it with gdb via QEMU. My problem is gdb doesn't stop after `break start_kernel`. More details is below.

My host system is ArchLinux `5.0.10-arch1-1-ARCH x86_64`.

Qemu is `QEMU emulator version 4.0.0`

gdb is `GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2.1`.

Debugged kernel is `linux-4.20.12`

I have done following steps:

1. Compile kernel with

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED is not set
```

2. Try to run LFS-8.4 system with it kernel via QEMU

```
qemu-system-x86_64 lfs-8.4-08052019.raw
```

System starts good.

3. Run this system with `stop CPU` and `gdbserver` options via QEMU

```
qemu-system-x86_64 lfs-8.4-08052019.raw -S -s
```

4. Start gdb

```
$ gdb
```

5. Load symbols

```
(gdb) file /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-4.20.12/vmlinux
Reading symbols from /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-4.20.12/vmlinux...done.
```

6. Connect to QEMU

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
0x000000000000fff0 in cpu_hw_events ()
```

7. Set break point

```
(gdb) break start_kernel
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff82761ab5: file init/main.c, line 538.
```

(I have tried hardware break point `hbreak`, but result is the same)

8. Continue

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Further system loads login prompt without any breaks and gdb doesn't show any new messages.
What I do wrong?

UPD: starting QEMU with embed `-kernel` facility give the same result

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-4.20.12/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -append 'root=/dev/sda3' -drive file=lfs-8.4-08052019.raw -S -s
```

UPD2: I have tried to start QEMU without `-S` key and run `target remote localhost:1234` in gdb immediately. QEMU have stopped loading at

```
Decompressing Linux... Parsing ELF... Performing relocations... done.
Booting kernel.
```

When I type `s` in gdb it says

```
(gdb) s
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

I suspect that debug symbols in vmlinux isn't related to bzImage. Maybe they was made wrong, but I don't how to make them another way.

UPD3: I have built kernel `2.6` in LFS-8.4 chroot environment. System isn't loaded, but kernel is successfully debugged by method described above! So, I think that it is problem of new kernels. Maybe I should switch off/on something in my 4.20.12 kernel, but I don't know what is exactly. For my purpose (reading Robert Love "Linux Kernel Development") kernel version 2.6 is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass nokaslr to kernel cmdline.

qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /mnt/lfs/sources/linux-4.20.12/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -append 'root=/dev/sda3 nokaslr' -drive file=lfs-8.4-08052019.raw -S -s